# ng-bootstrap: How to access nested components?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Suppose I have a parent componet with a template which looks something like this.

The tooltip is nested inside the modal which in turn, is nested inside the tab.

I am tyring to access the most inner component(tooltip) from the most outer component(the parent) so I can toggle it manually based on some conditions.

How can I acheive this?

```
<ngb-tabset>
 <ng-tab>
    ~
 </ng-tab>
 <ng-tab>
  <ng-template ngbTabContent>
    <ng-template  #content1 let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title">header</h4>
     </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <ng-template #tipContent1>Error Message</ng-template>
     <input type="email" class="form-control"  name="email" [(ngModel)]="email" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent1" #t1="ngbTooltip" required>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">footer</div>
    </ng-template>
  </ng-template>
 </ng-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

＊ I have no control over the child components, but only the parent.

Comment: I supouse you can access using a ViewChild in the parent and a ViewChild in a inner component (or use a service) https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild

Comment: I have no control over the child components...

Answer (score 0):

Use Shared Services:

**Service:**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    myMethod$: Observable<any>;
    private myMethodSubject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() {
        this.myMethod$ = this.myMethodSubject.asObservable();
    }

    myMethod(data) {
        console.log(data); // I have data! Let's return it so subscribers can use it!
        // we can do stuff with data if we want
        this.myMethodSubject.next(data);
    }
}
```

**Component1 (sender):**

```
export class SomeComponent {
    public data: Array<any> = MyData;

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod(this.data);
    }
}
```

**Component2 (receiver):**

```
export class SomeComponent2 {
    public data = {};

    public constructor(private myService: MyService) {
        this.myService.myMethod$.subscribe((data) => {
                this.data = data; // And he have data here too!
            }
        );
    }
}
```

With this approach, components (even not directly related) can be in constant communication.

[Check documentation!](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: @d-_-b If is not your code and you don't control it, could you post which library is it? It probably has some callback functions or maybe directives that you can use to trigger it. If not, you can always clone the repo, change it and pull request to add that feature... :D